# How to set language for django-pagination?

Tags: django, django-pagination

As you can see, django-pagination has polish (pl) translations - https://github.com/ericflo/django-pagination/tree/master/pagination/locale but I dont know, how to set polish language for django-pagination? (default english)

Comment: Is it the only place where the translation does not work? Do you have other pages in your django project where the translation is working? Are you using the  default template of django-pagination? If not, can you show your template and the location in your project?

Answer (score 3):

This should happen automatically.
Check your django settings if `USE_I18N` is set to `True` and if your `LANGUAGE_CODE` is set to `pl`.

For further information take a look at the [django localization page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/). You can find a more detailed documentation of how the translation in django works [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/).

There's also a [list of language codes](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html), I guess `pl` should be correct.

Comment: Believe me - I have set USE_I18N=True and my LANGUAGE_CODE=pl in my settings, yet I still see english text: "previous", "next" ...

Answer (score 2):

You can either change the language setting of your browser, which will send the appropriate headers with each request and trigger the translation to be used, or you can provide a language setting selection so the user can choose their language.

You can roll your own code to provide this interface or use [django-user-accounts](http://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/).

You also might want to check that you have the appropriate middleware installed as described in this [documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/i18n/#how-django-discovers-language-preference).